# Learning How to Use Regular Expressions to validate email address

Tags: regex

I appreciate there is a lot of questions on Regular expressions to validate email address on SO. However, I simply don't understand how to use them to strip out or validate an email address. 
I have visited multiple sites where the author claims to 99% be able to validate an email address. However, whenever I use an Regular Expression to validate the following I get nothing back

Toranto43.623409,-79.368683 Toranto  %6$^2  a.richey@mysite.com

I am completely new to Regular Expressions. So I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but could someone find a Regular Expression that will find the address a.richey@mysite.com from the above?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where is it going wrong?  In what programming language are you attempting to parse / validate?

Comment: I have tried \b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b

Comment: That’s great, but please update the question.  And please spell Toronto correctly.

Comment: I also tried the regular expression here .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

Comment: I also tried multiple expressions here http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=email

Comment: So, any one able to assist witht this question?

Answer (score 0):

The following RegEx worked like a dream:

[a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.*%+-]*.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}